# Use a referenced cell in a formula

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I was wanting help with my formula. In cells `A2:A4` I have the cells pulling in an image using the `IMAGE()` function. In cell `A6` I have it set to `=A2` and cell `C6` is set to `=A4`. Now in cell `D6` I want a formula that will add the number of oranges and kiwi berries together for Sam. What I need help with is I would like to make this sheet dynamic so that I can have different combinations of fruits along with the ability to add more fruits in the future. What I want is a function in `D6` that references cells `A6` and `C6` and then using those two cells I want to pull in the original cell for the fruits and use that original cell's row to pull in the data.

`D6` - `=D2+D4`. This would give me the sum of oranges and kiwi berries for Sam.

`D6` - `=ADDRESS(2,COLUMN())+ADDRESS(4,COLUMN())`. This would also give me the sum for Sam, but I can copy this across to Adam and Kara to get their sums as well.

`=CELL("row",A2)`. This will give me the row for oranges.

What I need is in the formula in `D6` I need it to look at `A6` which is looking at `A2` and pull the row of `A2`.

[image]

Comment: you should check out `=VLOOKUP()`

Comment: I agree I could use VLOOKUP() or and INDEX(MATCH()) function, however the fruit images don't necessarily have a value I can use in a lookup.

Comment: I think I could do it if I could pull the formula in A6 out as a string.

Comment: I'-'I I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Lolz I would if I had that capability. ;-) I'm rocking the elderly emoticons. :-)

Comment: You can use `=match(A6,A2:A4,0)` to find the height of the orange

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer to my question. In Google Sheets this is not an available function unless you script it. This however is possible in excel without scripting.

[Google Sheets - how do you get the formula from a cell instead of the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522305/google-sheets-how-do-you-get-the-formula-from-a-cell-instead-of-the-value)

Comment: I think what I am going to do is I am going to add hidden columns with data with which I can use either `VLOOKUP()` or `INDEX(MATCH())`.