# Google spreadsheet custom script reference

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I found this script that realized FORMULATEXT's excel function in google.

```
    function FORMULATEXT(A1Notation) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(A1Notation).getFormula();
}
```

But problem is for use it you need use quotations for reference like this

```
=formulatext("A1")
```

And link in formula didn't change when you move it in other cell.
How can i upgrade this script to fix it?

Comment: Use `CELLFORMULA` as described (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37341868/1330560)

Comment: i would like, but it doesn't work inside other formula.

Comment: You said the problems with `formulatext` were 1) "use quotations for reference" and 2) "link in formula didn't change when you move it in other cell". Well, `CELLFORMULA` fixes both of those problems. Whether it works inside other formula is a different issue altogether. Best that you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then create a new question.